# How to correctly code a Joomla MVC component to perform jQuery AJAX GETS/POSTS?

Tags: jquery, joomla

So, I've got this spectacular Joomla component that when finished, will bring world peace, and solve world hunger.  All I have to do is incorporate the code that gets called via the jquery .ajax calls. I currently have them in an external location so that the AJAX calls can get to them, but am not clear how to correctly place them in the Joomla Component structure.

I've done the research, trust me, but have only found a lot of discussion about "you could try this, or that".  Presumably it's because Joomla relies on mootools, so Jquery is generally out of the discussions, but we have this great library of jQuery routines in-house that I'd like to leverage *the right way*.

It seems to me that a view has to be created for each call, which seems like a lot of unnecessary work/overhead to accomplish it. (Like asking the pilot to check in to his flight with the passengers).  It also seems to me that it shouldn't be this difficult, so am confused about what I'm missing, or why there doesn't appear to be a straight answer.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**
Accepted answer from Soren because it answers the question directly, though I hadn't specified Joomla 1.5, I was able to quickly adapt his answer to work.

Honorable mention to Greg P though - his answer opened up a *world* of other possibilities that i hadn't considered for quick solutions to other projects/challenges that I have.

Here's the url I was able to successfully call *from* my component *to* my component using AJAX, and what I added to make it work.

```
index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&controller=ajax.raw&task=myfunction
```

**components\com_mycomponent\controllers\ajaxraw.php**

```
<?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );
    jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
    class MycomponentControllerAjaxraw extends JController
    {
        function myfunction()
        {
            echo json_encode("SomethingOrOther");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make Ajax calls to

```
index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=ajax.function_name&format=raw
```

You then need to make a new controller called ajax.raw.php and inside that you write functions with names that matches the "function_name" in the URL and they will be executed upon calling the URL.

From within those you can use models $this->getModel(); and views etc. when needed, or even be lazy and put your logic directly in the controller.

If you do not have a component then give the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) a try

Comment: i think this is the answer I've been looking for.  Where, in the regular component directory structure does ajax.raw.php go, and does the code need to account for format=raw (seems that would be a joomla concern to control template and other CMS output)

Comment: The devil is in the detail.  Not worked with mulitple controllers yet, so how does one name it - something like this?  class AjaxControllerRaw extends JController

Comment: I should have mentioned this is Joomla 1.5 that I'm modifying, but your answer gave me the starting point I needed.  I walked through what it did, and the dot in the task name seems to be dropped, so I adjusted accordingly.  I DID however, get it working as I had hoped, so I'm going to accept your answer, and add my own with how I got it working in j1.5  Thanks!

Comment: @Plummer it strips all the default HTML that is normally loaded from the template on any page view

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "official" way of doing it, but it's certainly clean and quick for me.  I just include the core Joomla files in a single file within my component folder and then use that core for my jQuery calls - no template, MVC, or CMS overhead to work through.  For Joomla 1.5, only 2 files are needed: joomla_platform.php to load the guts of Joomla based on Joomla's index.php, and another to use it and return something to jQuery.  See the docs at http://api.joomla.org.

```
From index.php
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

**EDIT:** Here's a watered down version of how I do it:

I suppose a word of warning is in order though.  I use this internally, so have nothing to worry about, but my example of returning the configuration is only to show you how to get the configuration, ***I wouldn't have this example output available for general use***.  The check in place here insures that an admin user is logged in, but you can adjust it however you'd like.

I should also mention that this doesn't need a component or jQuery to work.  I use the same 2 files to write quick standalone pages so that i don't have to author an entire component just to leverage the Joomla platform.  The index.php shown could just as easily output standard HTML instead of json encoded output to display a normal web page. It bypasses much of the usefulness of a framework and the CMS I suppose, but sometimes you don't need all the overhead for something specific.

**components\com_mycomponent\platform\joomla_platform.php:**

```
<?php
    /* If not already done, initialize Joomla framework */
    if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
        define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
        //        define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
        define ('JPATH_BASE', "c:\\wamp\\www\\");
        define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
        /* Required Files */
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
        /* To use Joomla's Database Class */
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
        require_once ( JPATH_LIBRARIES.DS.'joomla'.DS.'import.php'); // Joomla library imports.
        /* Create the Application */
        global $mainframe;
        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
    }
?>
```

**components\com_mycomponent\platform\index.php:**

```
<?php
    require_once('joomla_platform.php');
    $config = new JConfig();
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    //Make sure a logged in user is doing the request (not mandatory, but safer)
    //if(!$user->id) {
    //  die("Not logged in");
    if($user->gid < 23) {
        die('Administrators only!');
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM jos_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 /* Get the last registered user */";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $row = $db->loadAssoc();
        //echo json_encode($row);                       // Return only the SQL result
        //echo json_encode(get_object_vars($user));     // Return only the user object
        //echo json_encode(get_object_vars($config));   // Return only the config object
        echo json_encode(
        array_merge(                                    // Merge the arrays, and return them all
            $row,
            get_object_vars($user),
            get_object_vars($config)
            )
        );
    }
?>
```

**Sample jQuery use in a php file:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "components/com_mycomponent/platform/index.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(joomla) {
        alert('Joomla Platform info appended to myDiv for '+joomla.sitename);
        $.each(joomla, function(key, value) {
            $('#myDiv').append(key + ' : ' + value + '<br/>')
        });
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("Joomla Platform Error Status: " + xhr.status + " Thrown Errors: "+thrownError);
    }
});
```