# joomla component development with Ajax queries

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a PHP script used for AJAX queries, but I want them to be able to operate under the umbrella of Joomla's (2.5) framework so I can have session id's, user id's etc available to me.

For example:

```
$(function () {
 $.ajax({                                     
   url: 'ajax.php',   //the script to call to get data                     
   dataType: 'json'        //data format     
   ...
 });
});
```

Where ajax.php has code such as:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
```

From what I understand it's best to make your AJAX/JSON calls to a standard Joomla component. I don't know much about developing a MVC component but from what I can see it is way overkill for what I want to do.

Is there something else I could be using?

Comment: I have answered this question once already in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820052/how-to-correctly-code-a-joomla-mvc-component-to-perform-jquery-ajax-gets-posts/10833585#10833585

Comment: @SørenBeckJensen I've seen that but it answers with the indication that you already have a component built. This is my problem. Component development seems way overkill for what I want to do. Even the hello world component development tutorial is huge. There must be an easier shortcut way to get a component setup so I can use AJAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you  create a component you can create new `view` for raw queries for example `compoments/com_yourcomponent/views/ajax/view.raw.php` and put all logic and output in there
url will be `index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=ajax&format=raw`

or

you can to create new method in `controller.php` with `exit()` after print information and url will be `index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=ajax`

Comment: That's the problem, is creating a component. I can't see a easy way to just set one up without going through all the MVC stuff. Is there a way to create a component without going through the process of MVC?

Comment: copy components/com_contact/contact.php rename to yourcomponentname.php   
edit to remove helper including, change controller name.
Also copy controller.php, rename class name and add `function ajax()` with `exit();` before `}`

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible by way of the [Joomla Platform](http://api.joomla.org/).  The example I'll give you below is actually for J1.5, but is easily adaptable to J2.5 with some adjustment to the included files.

1. Create a joomla platform file to include as shown below:
2. Include that file in *your* script
3. Use the now-available Joomla environment for your functions.

Another **strong** recommendation is to implement a ReSTful API instead of your custom scripts.  It's outrageously simple using [Luracast Restler](http://luracast.com/products/restler/).  I had it up and running in about 10 minutes, then added the Joomla Framework as shown below, and had an *extremely* flexible Joomla based API using AJAX calls for my site in under an hour!  Best spent development time in *years*, as far as I'm concerned.

**yourscript.php**

```
require_once('joomla_platform.php');
/* Get some of the available Joomla stuff */
$config = new JConfig(); 
$db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->gid <25) {
    die ("YOU CANT BE HERE");
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($config,true)."</pre>";
```

**joomla_platform.php**

```
<?php
    /* Initialize Joomla framework */
    if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
        define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
        //        define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
        define ('JPATH_BASE', "c:\\wamp\\www");
        define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
        /* Required Files */
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
        /* To use Joomla's Database Class */
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
        require_once ( JPATH_LIBRARIES.DS.'joomla'.DS.'import.php'); // Joomla library imports.
        /* Create the Application */
        global $mainframe;
        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try again but I've gone down this path with 2.5 and didn't seem to find it that easy but with 1.5 it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create any custom files and add them into Joomla script. You just need a controller to serve ajax request. You don't even need a view (one way).

Your ajax call should be like these:

```
$(function () {
 $.ajax({                                     
   url: 'index.php?option=com_<component_name>&no_html=1task=<controller_name>.<controller_action>',  //not_html = 1 is important since joomla always renders it's default layout with menus and everything else, but we want the raw json output            
   dataType: 'json' //data format     
   ...
 });
});
```

And your controller:

```
    /*
    * @file admin/controller/<controller_name>.php
    */

class <component_name>Controller<controller_name> extends JController
{

        public function <controller_action>()
        {

         //do something
         $respnse['message'] = 'Your message for the view';
         die(json_encode($reponse));
        }
    }

...
```

This is just one of the examples of how it's could be done.