# button with sql consult

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a button in my website and I want to return a Sql consult when  I click it, I have to create a component  for this?

How do this in joomla?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, but there is a "Joomla-approved" shortcut using the [Joomla Platform](http://api.joomla.org/).  I just answered this for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454226/joomla-component-development-with-ajax-queries), but it applies to your situation as well, so you can refer to it for the details.

In short, these are the steps you'll need to follow

1. Create a joomla platform file to include in your script (details at the other answer).
2. Create a your PHP script that includes that file.
3. Create a link to your PHP file that now has the Joomla environment for your functions, (including SQL executions).